# Change a string into a string with the letters a-z in every character of the string

Tags: python, string

OK this is my code

import string
    key = "Dog"

```
keylist = list(key)

for char in string.ascii_lowercase:
    print char
```

How would i be able to loop through the list and change the first letter of Dog to a and then print it so it would be aog and then b so it would be bog and so on. Then move on to the o in dog and do the same thing and then move over to the g in dog and do the same thing.

Comment: Please provide more detail, what you've tried so far, where you are having trouble, and what your desired output is. But first read this: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

```
key = "dog"

for char_pos in range(len(key)):
    for alphabet_char in ascii_lowercase:
        print(key[:char_pos] + alphabet_char + key[char_pos + 1:])
```