# Replace a character with all alphabet in a string and store the generate the output in a list with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nlp, alphabetical

I want to replace each character in a string with all the alphabet and save the output in a list to work with it lately in a NLP project.

For example

```
var='abc'
```

Output expected

```
['bbc','cbc','dbc','ebc',...,'aac','acc','adc','aec',...,'aba','abb','abd','abe'...]
```

How can I do this with Python? Thanks

/Tried some codes but no luck

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change a string into a string with the letters a-z in every character of the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47983212/change-a-string-into-a-string-with-the-letters-a-z-in-every-character-of-the-str)

Comment: Please show the code you tried, even if it fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may achieve this using below *list comprehension* expression as:

```
>>> import string
>>> var='abc'

#                 to get the string of all the lowercase alphabets v
>>> [var[:i]+s+var[i+1:]for i in range(len(var)) for s in string.lowercase if s!=var[i]]
```

which will return:

```
[
 'bbc', 'cbc', 'dbc', 'ebc', 'fbc', 'gbc', 'hbc', 'ibc', 'jbc', 'kbc', 'lbc', 'mbc', 'nbc', 'obc', 'pbc', 'qbc', 'rbc', 'sbc', 'tbc', 'ubc', 'vbc', 'wbc', 'xbc', 'ybc', 'zbc', 
 'aac', 'acc', 'adc', 'aec', 'afc', 'agc', 'ahc', 'aic', 'ajc', 'akc', 'alc', 'amc', 'anc', 'aoc', 'apc', 'aqc', 'arc', 'asc', 'atc', 'auc', 'avc', 'awc', 'axc', 'ayc', 'azc', 'aba', 'abb', 'abd', 'abe', 'abf', 'abg', 'abh', 'abi', 'abj', 'abk', 
 'abl', 'abm', 'abn', 'abo', 'abp', 'abq', 'abr', 'abs', 'abt', 'abu', 'abv', 'abw', 'abx', 'aby', 'abz']
```

Answer (score 2):

What is the replace for if you are going to use the entire alphabet?
It seems like you are just trying to generate all possible permutations of the alphabet for a definite number of letters.

For which:

```
import itertools
import string
vars = [''.join(i) for i in itertools.product(string.ascii_lowercase, repeat = 3)]
```

would work

Comment: Punch out the original string ex post, and this is the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Or by this:

```
import itertools

allChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

allTriplets = itertools.permutations(allChars,3)
all = [''.join(x) for x in allTriplets if x != ('a','b','c')]
print(all)
```

this will produce all permutations of length 3 of all characters in `allChars` (as tuples) - the list comprehension then joins the tuples to strings and add  them into a list.

Comment: If I understood OP correctly, `'abc'` shouldn't be here.

Comment: @EricDuminil thanks, did not catch that. fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as l 
import itertools
var='abc'
final_data = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([[var[:i]+c+var[i+1:] for c in l if var[i] != c] for i in range(len(var))]))
```

Output:

```
['bbc', 'cbc', 'dbc', 'ebc', 'fbc', 'gbc', 'hbc', 'ibc', 'jbc', 'kbc', 'lbc', 'mbc', 'nbc', 'obc', 'pbc', 'qbc', 'rbc', 'sbc', 'tbc', 'ubc', 'vbc', 'wbc', 'xbc', 'ybc', 'zbc', 'aac', 'acc', 'adc', 'aec', 'afc', 'agc', 'ahc', 'aic', 'ajc', 'akc', 'alc', 'amc', 'anc', 'aoc', 'apc', 'aqc', 'arc', 'asc', 'atc', 'auc', 'avc', 'awc', 'axc', 'ayc', 'azc', 'aba', 'abb', 'abd', 'abe', 'abf', 'abg', 'abh', 'abi', 'abj', 'abk', 'abl', 'abm', 'abn', 'abo', 'abp', 'abq', 'abr', 'abs', 'abt', 'abu', 'abv', 'abw', 'abx', 'aby', 'abz']
```